# Rename ansi-term buffer

Tags: emacs

How does one rename a buffer that's associated with an ansi-term?

I'd like to create several buffers:

```
M-x ansi-term 
Run program: /bin/bash
```

and then rename these buffers to reflect what they are used for. Right now the defaults are:

```
*ansi-term* 
*ansi-term*<2> 
*ansi-term*<3>
```

But I'd like to rename them to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found an answer to my own question.

If I use a shell:

```
M-x shell
```

then I can access the mini-buffer and call M-x rename-buffer. Now I can name my shells to reflect what I'm using then for instead of guessing what shell or shell<1> or shell<2> is used for.

Digging further... I found a solution for

```
M-x ansi-term
```

If you use

```
C-x M-x rename-buffer
```

then you can access the mini-buffer in a ansi-term.

Answer (score 3):

From source article: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview
You can switch between so called line mode and char mode to achieve your goal.
Use Ctrl-C Ctrl-j to switch to line mode, then you can use classic commands like M-x rename-buffer
Use Ctrl-C Ctrl-k to return to char mode where each character is sent directly to the underlying inferior shell without preprocessing by Emacs